# Wordpress проблема при установке

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-403

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приветствую друзья, кто знает в чем может быть проблема при установке Wordpress.Все требования для установки wordpress выполненны(версия php и тд).Права на папки 755.Пробовал установить и в ручную через ftp и при помощи автоматической установки в панеле хостинга.Первый раз сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой, буду благодарен любой информации.

Comment: Этот текст - не из ядра WordPress. Пишите тому, кто наваял его.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду ?

Comment: Вот как выглядит установка WordPress https://monosnap.com/file/VUdpWVWy69ZB0Vl5QfF85MjPjbvn5S. Что за текст у вас на экране и откуда он - неизвестно. Пишите хостеру.

Comment: На скриншоте который я скинул указан этап подключения к БД,а на вашем уже следующий этап.И обратите внимание на консоль разработчика.К тому же причем тут хостер когда я скачал wordpress с офф сайта и установил по ftp.

Comment: У меня самый первый шаг на картинке, первее нет. И 403 - ответ сервера, который у хостера. Пишите ему.

Comment: Точнее, у меня второй экран. А первый - выбор языка https://monosnap.com/file/H1MCrkjOiWf1N70DAxTpOFGJUlvbMM

Comment: CMS была скачана с данного ресурса (https://ru.wordpress.org/download). Тот же самый движок что и установлен на хостинге где он работает некорректно,  устанавливаю для демонстрации на localhost, специально для вас https://imgur.com/a/rjLqOxX.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102902/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-nikita).